# AWS Lambda storage issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I got the following error when I ran python code on AWS lambda.

`"errorMessage": "[Errno 17] File exists: '/tmp/testdir/'"`

It occurs on the line `os.makedirs('/tmp/testdir/')`.

Before I didn't have this kind of error. Does this mean Lambda function preserves tmp directory?

Should I clean tmp directory everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the content of the Lambda diskspace at `/tmp` may be available to subsequent Lambda invocations (these are so-called 'warm start' invocations).

See [Understanding Container Reuse](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/).

You can clean up the `/tmp` folder before existing your Lambda function or you could use the following code to safely create the folder, ignoring the fact that it may already exist:

```
os.makedirs('/tmp/testdir/', exist_ok=True)
```